Simple MPI_File_open not working properly
I am trying to compile and run this simple C/MPI program (test.c), that only try to open (create, if non existent) a file, nothing else:
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int size, rank;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm comm;
    MPI_Comm_dup(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &comm);


    MPI_Comm_size(comm, &size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(comm, &rank);

    MPI_File file;
    char *filename="ttt.dat";
    MPI_File_open(comm, filename, MPI_MODE_CREATE | MPI_MODE_RDWR, MPI_INFO_NULL, &file);

    if (file != MPI_SUCCESS) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error fwrite to %s\n", filename);
        MPI_Abort(comm, 1);
    }

return 0;
}

This is what I do to compile and run the file, and the error that i get:
$ mpicc test.c
$ mpirun -np 3 --oversubscribe a.out
error fwrite to ttt.dat
error fwrite to ttt.dat
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
MPI_ABORT was invoked on rank 1 in communicator MPI COMMUNICATOR 3 DUP FROM 0
with errorcode 1.

NOTE: invoking MPI_ABORT causes Open MPI to kill all MPI processes.
You may or may not see output from other processes, depending on
exactly when Open MPI kills them.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
error fwrite to ttt.dat
[pc:08014] 2 more processes have sent help message help-mpi-api.txt / mpi-abort
[pc:08014] Set MCA parameter "orte_base_help_aggregate" to 0 to see all help / error messages

What is happening? I cannot figure out what is wrong with my code, also it worked in the past, but since today it stopped working properly.
Also, rarely an error with "bad file descriptor" appears in the terminal error log - I don't have it anymore but I will post it if it happens to me again.
(I know that the file is not closed at the end of the code, but the program execution cannot even reach the point in which it should happen)

You need to check the actual status rather than just checking whether it failed. I assume that MPI will provide a proper value to indicate why the open failed.

Your test is wrong. It should be int ret=MPI_File_open(...); if (MPI_SUCCESS != ret) ...

Compile with -Wall, your compiler should have catched that.

Thank you for your answers. I just checked the status code and it is 0, that is MPI_SUCCESS (tested via MPI_Error_string). I think I have mistaken what is tested: the return code should be MPI_SUCCESS, not the file handle. And I am testing the file handle. Well... I think this was the problem. I am currently checking furthermore to be sure, but if this is the cause, I apologize for the silly question. Again, thank you for your comments and your patience!
